# How do I recreate the original file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Working on a Javascript-based file encryption program. It works great for text files, but I'm trying to do other data (images, etc) and the decrypted file isn't matching. In my program, I use the following code to read the file that the user provides:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
let file = UI.file.input.files[0];
reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
```

The reader then adds that to a Javascript object that contains other information, like the date and file name. Then, that's stringified using JSON.stringify() and encrypted. When the encryption is completed, the file gets saved as a different file format with the encrypted JSON inside of it. The code for that is:

```
let message = // ENCRYPTED FILE STRING
let file = new Blob([message], {
    type: 'text/plain'
});
let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

The url is then attached to a link element on the page. That's all working fine.

To decrypt it, the file is again provided by the user and runs through the same reader as used above. It's decrypted successfully and the resulting string is again put into an object using JSON. **Up to that point, it works exactly as it's supposed to. It works fine if what I'm decrypting is a text file, but if I do an image file it all goes bad.**

To save the decrypted file, I use this code:

```
let message = // DECRYPTED DATA CONVERTED TO AN OBJECT
let fileName = message.name;
let fileType = message.type;
let file = new Blob([message.data], {
    type: fileType
});
let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

The original file and and original file type are both pulled from the file before it's encrypted and added to the object that has the file data. Like I said, there's no problem with the encryption or decryption process. I've used a HEX viewer to check and the string that is being put into the encryption process is identical to the one coming out. I'm guessing the issue is somewhere in my final block of code.

My best guess is something to do with encoding, although I'm not sure exactly what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, `.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8')` won't work with images.

Comment: UTF-8 is specifically for text. If you're reading binary data, such as images, you shouldn't decode it as text.

Comment: That's what I figured. So what would I need to use to pull the data as a binary that can still be stringifyed when added to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) and strip the `data:*/*;base64,` from the string. Then you'll have a base64 encoded string that you can put into JSON.

Comment: Ended up taking a similar approach. Read the file as an array buffer and then converted to base64. I needed the file data not encoded in base64 when it's first read so that I can do a file validity test.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. I was thinking of also suggesting something like `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()`